# How to propagate 4XX errors to end-user which occurred during internal communication between upstream micro-services?

Tags: microservices

Let's say I have three micro-services A, B, C.

Assume, that the client calls

```
client--> A --> B --> C
```

Client call to micro-service A , which then calls to B and B then calls to C

If any of B or C returns 5XX,  A will show a 502 Error to user.

```
client --> A --> 5XX
or client --> A --> B--> 5XX
```

The client receives the 502 Response with the actual error in the details message.

Assuming that there was a bad request error(say in B or C) or 4XX error, what should A show to the user? A 502 Bad Gateway or propagate a 4XX error to the user?

```
client --> A --> 4XX
or client --> A --> B--> 4XX
```

What should the client see?

Should it be a 502 Bad Gateway containing a 4xx error with error details in response body?

For example:

```
502 Bad Gateway 
{

  "errors" : {
    "code" : "InternalError",
    "message" : "Internal error occured please try after some time.",
    "details" : "Error in validating file 123-23-234 format while unzipping."  

   }

 }
```

or

should it be 4XX error with error details in response body?

```
4XX Bad Request

{

  "errors" : {
    "code" : "InvalidFileFormat",
    "message" : "Error in validating file 123-23-234 format while unzipping."
   }

 }
```

What about 401 Auth errors or time out errors ?

Comment: Good question! So in order to accomplish a task, you have to make two direct calls to other microservices. It smells a little bit, doesn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good practices to propagate errors through micro services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610425/good-practices-to-propagate-errors-through-micro-services)

Comment: It's _such_ a good question it has about five or six dupes out there already. The other good question is, do I close it as opinion-based or as a dupe?

Answer (score 0):

4XX codes indicate a user fault. If the user makes a proper call to service A, but service A makes a faulty call to service B, then there's a bug in service A, and a "500 Internal error" must be returned.

403 may be exception, because it could lead to a situation of heavy-coupling if service A has to be aware of all permissions required by service B before to invoke it. So sometimes it's ok that service A invokes service B, and if service B returns a 403, then service A returns the 403.